# How to change this array to give physics bodies to each individual node(bit masks)?

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have dice falling from the top of my screen. There are five different ones with different faces and they are all randomly generated like so:

```
   var imageNames = ["Dice", "Dice2", "Dice3", "Dice4"]
    let imageIndex=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageNames.count)))

    let die=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageNames[imageIndex])
    die.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(45, 45))
    die.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    die.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    let positions = [
        CGPointMake(150, 600),
        CGPointMake(300, 600),
        CGPointMake(100, 600),
    ]

    let randomPositionIndexs = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(positions.count)))
    die.position = positions[randomPositionIndexs]
     die.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
    die.runAction(
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -900,
            duration: NSTimeInterval(10.8)))
    addChild(die)
```

So my question is, is there a way to make it so the nodes are still generating randomly, but each node is being called on its own so I can uniquely identify each one? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, generate a random number in [0, diceCount-1]:

```
let diceCount = 4
let index=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(diceCount)))
```

Next, use string interpolation to construct the file names of the dice (i.e., Dice1, Dice2, ...)

```
let die = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dice\(index+1)")
```

and create and configure a physics body

```
die.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(45, 45))
die.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
die.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

Lastly, set the category bit mask based on the random number (0 - diceCount-1). Use `index` and the bitwise shift left operator to calculate the corresponding bit value (i.e., 1, 2, 4, ...)

```
die.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(0x1 << index)
```

and one more thing...

```
die.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(0x1 << index)
```

Comment: Okay so im kinda confused about category bit mask. How does this differentiate each node? I need each  one to individually collide with the die I have on the bottom (one collides with one, two collides with two, etc)

Comment: Yes, but I'm still confused as to how they're all separate bit masks

Comment: DIce 1's bit mask is 1, Dice 2's bitmask is 2, Dice 3's bitmask is 4, etc. You can use this to uniquely identify each dice type. Add they are configured to collide with the same dice of the same type.

Comment: So is that's being called automatically?

Comment: What is being called automatically?

Comment: The bit masks for each die. Do I have to still type those out? Also how would I set the by masks for the bottom nodes which are in a separate function since the index isn't declared globally?

Comment: The bit mask are set with the last two lines of code in my answer. Are the bottom nodes the dices that falls from the top?

Comment: Ok cool. No, I have five separate die on the bottom of my screen that the falling ones collide with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101111/discussion-between-epsilon-and-iheartappsllc).